# Nokogiri not parsing XML string correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

EDIT: the xml is parsed through a `curl` command. It is not initialized like the example
I have an XML string

```
xml = <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?>
      <Document xmlns=somexmlns>
            <tag> some data </tag>
     </Document>
```

When I try to parse with Nokogiri, (I tried all 3)
`Nokogiri::XML(xml)`
`Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)`
`Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml).remove_namespaces!`
I get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document/>
```

I know I can remove the `xmlnx` tag before parsing it with Nokogiri, but I would like to know why this is happening and how I can resolve it without modifying the XML itself.

Comment: What code did you try? How did you set `xml`? Now it looks with syntax errors.

Comment: i passed in xml through a curl command, and I did verify that the xml is correct. the functions I tried are in the question

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><document xmlns="somexmlns"><tag> some data </tag></document>')
 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fda1d0c9dd8 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fda1d0c9b1c name="document" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fda1d0c9acc href="somexmlns"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fda1d0c9770 name="tag" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fda1d0c9acc href="somexmlns"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fda1d0c93ec " some data ">]>]>]> 

doc.children.text
 => " some data "
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about quotes. Why don't you use them?

Unfortunately, the quotation from [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) is inserted incorrectly (because of quotes), so I wrote it down as a code.

```
# To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as " &apos; ", and the double-quote character (") as " &quot; ".
```

Look:

```
xml = <<-BADXML
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?>
<Document xmlns=somexmlns>
<tag> some data </tag>
</Document>
BADXML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc

# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <Document/>
```

```
xml = <<-GOODXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="somexmlns">
<tag> some data </tag>
</Document>
GOODXML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc

# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
# <Document xmlns="somexmlns">
# <tag> some data </tag>
# </Document>
```

Also it's better to use lowercase letters like `<document></document>`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I forgot to set the data type as `text/xml` in curl.

Comment: In any case, use quotes for XML attributes. I have reproduced your error, look at answer